# Incorrect information displayed when slider is moved (intermittent)

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

All, the following code graphs 10 different solutions for a first order ODE and allows the user to modify certain equation parameters to see how the graph is affected:

```
Manipulate[
(*Find 10 different solutions for the ODE*)
eqn = {a y''[t] == b y[t] + d, y'[0] == c};
sol = DSolve[eqn, {y[t]}, {t}];
func[t_] = y[t] /. sol[[1]];
t[x_] = Table[func[t] /. C[1] -> j, {j, 1, 10}];

(*Display graph*)
Plot[Evaluate[t[x]], {t, -tmax, tmax}], 

(*Variables to parameterize*)
{a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, -1, 1, 1}, {c, -10, 10, 1}, 
{d, 0, 100, 10}, {tmax, 1, 10, 1},

(*Aesthetic labeling stuff*)
Delimiter,
Dynamic[Style[Row[{"Input: ", a , " y''(t) = ", 
b, " y(t) + ", d, ", y'(0) = ", c}], 12]],
Delimiter,
Dynamic[Style[Row[{"Output: ", func[t]}], 12]],

(*Misc. Manipulate stuff*)
ContinuousAction -> True, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, c, tmax, d}]
```

The problem that arises is the equation that is displayed after the "Output:" label. If you are patient enough, and move around the sliders (I have been varying parameter d), you will occasionally see the equation display as something like:

[image]

When it should be:

[image]

There are also some funky little things I have noticed like the slider "dragger" in picture 1 is still highlighted even after I release it.

Are there any glaring things that I am doing incorrectly that could be causing these symptoms? Is there anyone else that can reproduce the problem?

One other thing - I cannot make this problem happen if I use the stepper controls instead of using my mouse to change the value of the slider.

Answer (score 5):

The use of `t` as an iterator variable inside the `Plot` command is, I think, leaking out into the `Dynamic` containing your "Output" line on occasion.  In general, your overuse of the variable `t` is confusing at a minimum, and potentially error-prone.  I made two changes to your code.  First, I changed `t[x_]` to `funcs[x_]`, which shouldn't affect functionality, but does make it a lot easier to figure out what's going on.  Second, I replaced the iterator variable used by `Plot`.  Here's the code:

```
Manipulate[
 (*Find 10 different solutions for the ODE*)
 eqn = {a y''[t] == b y[t] + d, y'[0] == c};
 sol = DSolve[eqn, {y[t]}, {t}];
 func[t_] = y[t] /. sol[[1]];
 funcs[x_] = Table[func[t] /. C[1] -> j, {j, 1, 10}];

 (*Display graph*)
 Plot[Evaluate[funcs[x] /. t -> val], {val, -tmax, tmax}],

 (*Variables to parameterize*)
 {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, -1, 1, 1}, {c, -10, 10, 1},
 {d, 0, 100, 10}, {tmax, 1, 10, 1},

 (*Aesthetic labeling stuff*)
 Delimiter, 
 Dynamic[Style[
   Row[{"Input: ", a, " y''(t) = ", b, " y(t) + ", d, ", y'(0) = ", 
     c}], 12]], Delimiter, 
 Dynamic[Style[Row[{"Output: ", func[t]}], 12]],

 (*Misc. Manipulate stuff*)
 ContinuousAction -> True, SaveDefinitions -> True,
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, c, tmax, d}]
```

I couldn't reproduce your problem, so I can't guarantee this fixes it, but I think it is likely to.

Comment: What can I say, "t" is my favorite character in the alphabet! In all seriousness, with the changes you proposed, the problem is no longer evident. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why the slider "dragger" stays highlighted when it should no longer be (see picture 1 of the original post)? This occurs if you click on the slider away from the dragger, and it remains highlighted until you grab the dragger and move it again...

Comment: I believe you did not properly localize `x`, `y`, and `t`, and further that you should have done so as your code will be considered an authoritative example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Localizing `t` would require throwing multiple `Block`s into the code to preserve the output form (which would not be preserved by `DynamicModule`, etc.).  I agree that this would be the proper thing to do, but I didn't want to complexify the answer by focusing on points the author didn't ask.  Nonetheless, I will point out for posterity that Mr.Wizard is right in saying this is not the code as I would have written it.

Comment: @John lol -- okay, good enough :-)